# Extracting nested JSON data

Tags: node.js, json, nested, extract

I'm fetching data from an API which gives the response as a JSON object.

```
[
  {
    "id": 48191,
    "title": "Apple Crumble Recipe",
    "image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/48191-312x231.jpg",
    "imageType": "jpg",
    "usedIngredientCount": 1,
    "missedIngredientCount": 2,
    "missedIngredients": [
         {
            "id": 4073,
            "amount": 35,
            "unit": "g",
            "unitLong": "grams",
            "unitShort": "g",
            "aisle": "Milk, Eggs, Other Dairy",
            "name": "margarine",
            "original": "35 g margarine or butter",
            "originalString": "35 g margarine or butter",
            "originalName": "margarine or butter",
            "metaInformation": [],
            "meta": [],
            "image": "https://spoonacular.com/cdn/ingredients_100x100/butter-sliced.jpg"
         },
         {
            "id": 8120,
            "amount": 35,
            "unit": "g",
            "unitLong": "grams",
            "unitShort": "g",
            "aisle": "Cereal",
            "name": "rolled oats",
            "original": "35 g rolled oats",
            "originalString": "35 g rolled oats",
            "originalName": "rolled oats",
            "metaInformation": [],
            "meta": [],
            "image": "https://spoonacular.com/cdn/ingredients_100x100/rolled-oats.jpg"
         }
       ],
   {...More objects...}
]
```

I'm new to node.js, but I am able to extract the "id", "title", and "image" just fine, but I'm having trouble extracting the data nested inside missedIngredients array.

From the missedIngredients array, I want just the originalString.

This is what I have done so far:

```
// recipes is the array that comes from the JSON object
const result = []
            recipes.forEach(element => {
                result.push({
                    id: element.id,
                    title: element.title,
                    image: element.image,
                    missedIngredientCount: element.missedIngredientCount,
                    missedIngredients: [{
                        originalString: element.missedIngredients.originalString
                    }]  // need to extract data from missed ingredients
                })
            })
```

I know what I did will not work because element.missedIngredients is an array, not an object so I wouldn't be able to access originalString on it. What I thought to do is something like:

```
missedIngredients: {[
    originalString: element.missedIngredients[i].originalString
}]
```

Do I need to write nested for loop? Thanks in advance! I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try map method.

```
missedIngredients: element.missedIngredients.map(missed => {
     return {originalString: missed.originalString}
})
```